# Four people throw a balanced tetrahedron four times. What are the odds all numbers are different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Four people throw a balanced tetrahedron four times each, with its
> faces numbered from 1 to 4. What are the odds all scored numbers are
> different? (by scored I mean the face that was turned down after the
> tetrahedron was thrown).

I did:

- total possibilities = $4*4*4*4 = 4^4$
- all different = $4*3*2*1 = 4!$
- probability of getting all numbers different: $$ \frac{4!}{4^4}$$

  But this is the probability of getting all numbered different in *one throw.* To get them in all 4 throws, I could do either:
  $$^4C_4 * (\frac{3}{32})^4*(1-\frac{3}{32})^{(4-4)}=$$
  $$1 * \frac{3}{32}^4 * 1 = $$
  $$\frac{3}{32}^4$$

or $$\frac{3}{32}*\frac{3}{32}*\frac{3}{32}*\frac{3}{32} = (\frac{3}{32})^4$$

However, my book says the solution is just $\frac{4!}{4^4}$.

Did I misunderstand something? I copied the problem as it is.

Comment: I agree that the phrasing is unclear.  What's a "scored number"?  If I throw a die four times...which number counts as my score?  All four of my results?  Just the biggest?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu This isn't a regular die, it's a tetrahedron. The one that counts is the one on the face that is turned down

Comment: But you said I throw the die four times.  That would suggest that I have four scored numbers, no?  Making sixteen scored numbers all in all.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel But should't the number of ways of throwing 4 dice be $4^4*4^4*4^4*4^4$? And the phrasing is unclear, I don't understand if what it is wanted is that all numbers are different in each throw or in all throws. Which do you think it is?

Comment: @lulu yes, but what I don't understand is if those numbers, ordered in groups of four depending on the person that scored them, have to be all different in each group, all different in each person or both. The phrasing is very confusing.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel But each dice is thrown four times each, so you'd have $(4^4)^4$ total possible combinations and $4!^4$ ways of them being all different. And $\frac{4!^4}{4^{16}}=(\frac{3}{32})^4$

Comment: I think I may have misread the question, please stop.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ok, I apologize. I was just trying to make sure I understood you suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure the book says that *four* people *each* roll the die *four* times?  For the book's answer, $4!/4^4$, to make sense, either four people each roll the die *once*, or *one* person rolls the die four times.  So either you misread the problem (which happens to all of us on occasion) or the book's author made a mistake (which sounds like the more likely case here).

Comment: @BarryCipra yes, that's what it says.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, then there is another little quirk in the book's answer:  $4!/4^4=3/32$ is a *probability*; the corresponding *odds* are $3:29$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've solved the stated problem correctly.

The odds of getting different numbers with one throw is $4!/4^4 = 3/32$, and the odds of doing so four times in a row is $(3/32)^4$.

Comment: So, basically it's my book that is wrong?

Comment: That's correct.